# Custom form page before wizardform - how to quit directly?

Tags: inno-setup

I created an autorun.exe with inno setup, with a custom form page.
Now when I click on exit or close, the inno setup welcome page appears and starts to install.
How can I set the exit and close button (bisystemmenu) to quit from setup, or prevent wizardform to initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you're showing the form from.
If in InitializeSetup() then just return false after the window is closed.